# Get from IQueryable to IEnumerable

Tags: casting, f#

this should be a quick one for all you f# rockers, but it's got me stuck at the moment.

I've got an F# type which I'm trying to get to implement a c# interface

```cs
public interface ICrudService<T> where T: DelEntity, new()
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
}
```

here's how it's implemnted in c#:

```cs
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
{
    return repo.GetAll();
}
```

`repo.GetAll` returns an `IQueryable`, but the c# compiler knows enough to convert to `IEnumerable` because `IQueryable<T> : IEnumerable<T>`. but In F# the compiler can't work it and I've tried a few attempt to cast it correctly

```
type CrudService<'T when 'T :(new : unit -> 'T) and 'T :> DelEntity>(repo : IRepo<'T>) = 
    interface ICrudService<'T> with
         member this.GetAll () = 
            repo.GetAll<'T>
```

this is giving me a type mismatch error

Comment: What is the exact message? (Reading it could have let you suss it out yourself)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to cast to `IEnumerable<'T>`:

```
type CrudService<'T when 'T :(new : unit -> 'T) and 'T :> DelEntity>(repo : IRepo<'T>) = 
        interface ICrudService<'T> with
             member this.GetAll () = 
                repo.GetAll() :> IEnumerable<'T>
```

Comment: That did it. I had tried the cast to IEnumerable, but what I was missing was the brackets after the function call on GetAll.

Answer (score 1):

What if you used [Seq.cast<'T?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370344.aspx) It sounds like it just needs to be casted to the correct Type. Since IEnumerables are implemented differently in F#  than they are in C#.

```
let seqCast : seq<int> = Seq.cast repo.GetAll<'T>
```