# Converting from IQueryable to IEnumerable

Tags: c#

How do I convert from `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable`? I looked at another post [Get from IQueryable to IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973233/get-from-iqueryable-to-ienumerable) but it's not generic enough to reuse? Can anyone provides a generic reusable way to do this?

```
public class SoftwareProductRepository
{
    BitDatabaseEntities bitDB = new BitDatabaseEntities();
    public IEnumerable<BuildMetrics> GetBuildMetrics()
    {

        var list = (from r in bitDB.bit_sanity_results select r);

        return list;
    }
}
```

Error message:

> Cannot implictly converty type
>   `'System.Linq.IQueryable<Dashboard.EntityFramework.bit_sanity_results>'`
>   to
>   `'System.Collections.IEnumerable<Dashboard.Model.ApiModels.BuildMetrics>'`.An
>   explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Have you checked this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842176/convert-an-iqueryable-linq-query-to-ienumerablet-cancels-out-linq-optimized-wa

Comment: try `.ToEnumerable()`.

Comment: The VillateIdiot - where exactly?

Comment: Just a side note - do you know that `BitDatabaseEntities` is an `IDisposable` and therefore you need to make `SoftwareProductRepository` an `IDisposable` too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try converting queryable to enumerable with this:

```
(from r in bitDB.bit_sanity_results select r).AsEnumerable();
```

This will give you an enumerable collection but I think you may have to generate `BuildMetrics` objects from `bit_sanity_results` that are returned by this. Like:

```
(from r in bitDB.bit_sanity_results select new BuildMetrics{
       <some BuildMetrics property>=r.<some bit_sanity_results property>
        }).AsEnumerable();
```

---

**Example**

```
public class ReturnClass
{
    public string SSId{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Table from which we select:

```
table values_store
(
    ss_id varchar(50),
    user_name varchar(250)
)

public class ReturnValuesRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<ReturnClass> GetReturnClasses()
    {   
        //As commented by @Enigmativity if your `BitDatabaseEntities` is `IDisposable` (sure if it inherits from `DbContext`) you should wrap it in a `using` block
        using(var db = new ValuesEntities())
        {
            var list = (from r in db.values_store select new 
                   ReturnClass
                     {
                         SSId=r.ss_id,
                         Name=r.user_name
                    }).AsEnumerable();

            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this throws an error ` "cannot implicity convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Dashboard.EntityFramework.bit...' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Dashboard.Model.ApiModels.BuildMetrics>'.An explicit conversion exists`

Comment: I don't know what properties are there in `bit_sanity_results` or `BuildMetrics` classes. But you will get an Idea that you need to create objects in `select` statement.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot - You can't have `var` as a class-level variable declaration.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot also there is no need to use `.AsEnumerable()` anywhere, since `IQueryable` already implements it.

Comment: Enigmativity - can you throw more light on your comment?@TheVillageIdiot - do you follow Enigmativity comment?

Comment: @user3508811 member fields (variables declared at class level) must be explicitly declared as their actual type, not as a var.

Comment: @alisson you are right need to move var into function or put class there. Also *asenumerable* satisfies compiler

Answer (score 1):

The conversion in this case should actually be implicit as [`IQueryable<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562(v=vs.110).aspx).

Your problem here is a type mismatch, as you are getting `IQueryable<bit_sanity_results>` but are trying to return `IEnumerable<BuildMetrics>`.

You'd need to project the `IQueryable<bit_sanity_results>` to `IEnumerable<BuildMetrics>`.

Something like this:

```
public class SoftwareProductRepository
{
    BitDatabaseEntities bitDB = new BitDatabaseEntities();
    public IEnumerable<BuildMetrics> GetBuildMetrics()
    {
        return bitDB.bit_sanity_results.Select(r => new BuildMetrics(...));
    }
}
```

Comment: this throws an error "cannot implicity convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Dashboard.EntityFramework.bit...' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Dashboard.Model.ApiModels.BuildMetrics>'.An explicit conversion exists

Comment: @user3508811 so you're not using exactly this example. This is the right way of doing what you want. If you are doing something like `List<BuildMetrics> myList = GetBuildMetrics()` it's going to throw the error you said.